# Updating TP/SL of an active position with pybit

Tags: python, api, bybit, pybit

Hello Stack Overflow community,
I hope you're all doing well and having a great day!

I'm having an issue with the **pybit** package in Python, and I was hoping that someone here might be able to help me out.

I am trying to **edit** the **take profit and stop loss** of an **active position** on **Bybit** futures markets.
To do so, I'm using the official Python package identified by the Bybit exchange, pybit.

I'm specifically using the '**set_trading_stop**' function, but I keep encountering an error message.

Here is the Python code that I am using to call the function:

```
session_auth.set_trading_stop(orderId=myorderid, symbol=crypto, stopLoss='25000', category='linear', positionIdx=0, slTriggerBy='MarkPrice')
```

The error message that I get is the following:

```
InvalidRequestError: Not modified (ErrCode: 130127) (ErrTime: 06:43:33).
Request → POST https://api.bybit.com/private/linear/position/trading-stop: {'api_key': 'xxx', 'category': 'linear', 'orderId': '67bf2151-1f30-4b33-b2b8-332023a33f2c', 'positionIdx': 0, 'recv_window': 5000, 'slTriggerBy': 'MarkPrice', 'stopLoss': '25000', 'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'timestamp': 1681886613451, 'sign': 'xxx'}.
```

I have searched on forums and Stack Overflow, but I have only found responses for the ccxt package. I would prefer to use the pybit package, as it is the official package identified by the Bybit exchange.

The pybit package is a public archive, so I am unable to create an issue on Github. Therefore, I am posting my issue here on Stack Overflow in the hopes of finding a solution.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it!
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day,

You are probably using an older version of the pybit library, Bybit has updated its rest api to version 5 and the method "https://api.bybit.com/private/linear/position/trading-stop" has been replaced by the newer "https://api.bybit.com/v5/position/trading-stop".

Further, when setting the profit target and stop loss, the parameter "orderId" is not pass on the api, but only the symbol on which you want to adjust the open position.

I performed testing on new version pybit client (actually version 5.3.0) for the above values and the stop loss adjustment went smoothly.

**Notes**:

- If you once set the stop loss to the value of 25,000 usd, and call the method again with the same stop loss value, the api returns the error message "34040 - Set TP/SL/TS not modified". This is fine, because you are setting the stop loss to the same value that is already set.
- The pybit 5.3.0 library requires Python 3.9.1 and higher to function properly.

**Links**

- [Bybit api doc - method trading-stop](https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/v5/position/trading-stop)
- [Last version of pybit on pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/pybit/)

**Code example**

```py
from pybit.unified_trading import HTTP

class UpdatingTakeProfitAndStopLossActivePosition(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_update_stop_loss_active_position(self):
        pybit_client = HTTP(
            testnet=True,
            api_key="",
            api_secret=""
        )

        response = pybit_client.set_trading_stop(
            category="linear",
            symbol="BTCUSDT",
            stopLoss="25000",
            slTriggerBy="MarkPrice",
            positionIdx=0
        )

        print("Response: {}".format(response))

        self.assertEqual(response["retCode"], 0)
        self.assertEqual(response["retMsg"], "OK")
```

**requirements.txt**

```
pybit==5.3.0
```

**Response example**

```json
{'retCode': 0, 'retMsg': 'OK', 'result': {}, 'retExtInfo': {}, 'time': 1685467952890}
```

Comment: Hi Jiri, thx for the clean answer, all worked well !